# Encryption of password while logging in

Tags: encryption, password-protection

When we log in to a website like Gmail we give our password , Now Gmail is a Https website hence during transit, the password cannot be sniffed by Man in the middle attack ,If there is a SSL MITM ,then the password is seen in cleartext.

Is there a mechanism ,which encrypts the password during log in i.e even after SSL  MITM the attacker would only get the encrypted password.

This would be client side functionality using javascripts , right?

But again the client can choose to prevent or modify the scripts.

Or is there any other mechanism?

Answer (score 0):

You could hash your username and password at the browser/server and then compare hashes at the business layer.  This will prevent MITM attacks and allow the BO to validate credentials.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Javascript, but then you (1) have to get the Javascript safely to the user and (2) exchange keys to do the encryption.

While there is some value in protecting the password, if the SSL session is compromised the MITM can hijack the session and all the data, or prompt the user to change their password and just collect it.

You could use OpenId, but then you only move the problem of authentication to the OpenId server. You still need a way to get the user's secret to the server.

So, generally, clear-text passwords over SSL to establish a new, authenticated, session cookie is the way to go. Anything else reduces down to your orignal shared secret problem or the web browser not having anything but SSL to work with.

Comment: As far as password transmission, it's only SSL.

Comment: I should add to that, banks do use a three-step login process in which you:
1) Submit your login name. The bank responds with 3 security questions.
2) You answer the security questions. The bank responds with a password field and a picture that the user selected when setting up the account.
3) User submits the password if the picture is the expected pre-selected picture.

Some banks will "register" a computer which skips step 2 after you've done it once. All of the data transmission, however, is protected by SSL. Hope that helps!